# Is there a way to show in game time?

Tags: ps3, minecraft-legacy-console

There are a few questions about writing a mod to tell the "in game time" in minecraft, but they all indicate a mod.

I'm running MC on a PS3, if I can apply mods, I sure don't know how...

Is there a way to

1. display the in game time on a PS3?
2. Write/apply a mod that could get me the time?

Comment: I assume you are looking for something more sophisticated than a [clock](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Clock)?

Answer (score 1):

> Display the in game time on a PS3?

As [MrLemon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/249998/is-there-a-way-to-show-in-game-time#comment345834_249998) said, you can craft a [Clock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Clock) that will show you the time-lapse between day and night.

> Write/apply a mod that could get me the time?

You can't mod Minecraft on the PS3. The only editions that you can mod are the [Pocket Edition](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition) (Android) and the [Java Edition](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition) (Windows, Mac & Linux).